# can't write link to Get method using jsp

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I wrote in my jsp page the next link:

```
<a href="Controller?pageName=OptionCategory&pageCommand=Map"  data-role="button">Map</a>
```

I want to send parameters to my controller (the controller is servlet).

BUT the problem is that in the browser it show's:

```
"http://localhost:8080/Attraxions4/Controller#/Attraxions4/Controller?pageName=OptionCategory&pageCommand=Map"
```

instade of:

```
"http://localhost:8080/Attraxions4/Controller?pageName=OptionCategory&pageCommand=Map"
```

what is this sign number #?
why it copy again the root folders?

what can i do to fix it ??

thank you!!   :)

Comment: the solution is to add _self to the href
<a href="link" target="_self"> clickToLink</a>

Answer (score 0):

> what is this sign number #?

It is a fragment identifier. It indicates the end of the part of the URL to send to the server and indicates the id of an element to scroll to.

It is often abused to store data for use with Ajax requests.

> what can i do to fix it ?

Find the JavaScript you have that is hijacking the normal functionality of your links and remove it.